# Excel-Need Help Refining Categories

Tags: excel, categories

I am in need of an Excel function to help with the following.
I have a list of products, that I have just finished assigning keywords to. I need to make them into filters on a website, but must put them in easily readable, user friendly categories. There are about 40,000 items divided into 100 categories, about 30-140 keywords in each category. I derived the keywords from the item descriptions, so some of them are strange.

An example is-I have a bunch of items(abrasive wheels) that are for Cosmetic Grain Finishing, Satin Finishing, and Antique Finishing. I want to assign these all to a new category in the next column and with "Aesthetic Finishing" corresponding to each item where the keywords appear.

The problem I have is that I also want to assign "Best Disc", "Best Standard Abrasives", "Highest Quality", and "Highest Performing, Longest Lasting" to something like "Best in Class" in the same column as the "Aesthetic Finishing".

I was trying to work with VLOOKUP but can't get it to work the way I'd like. I'd also like to be able to drag the formula down the new column I create and not have to drag functions around to the corresponding row with the keywords. Any help is appreciated! I'm not sure if all the things I'd like are possible so any tips to speed it up are also appreciated.

More detailed example of data
Column C: -which was derived from keywords in descriptions so spelling and syntax varies

- Portability
- Remove Coatings
- Remove Coatings
- Remove Coatings
- Smoothes, Deburrs and Finishes
- Coating Removal
- Coating Removal
- Convolute Wheel
- Convolute Wheel
- Smoothes, Deburrs and Finishes
- Satin Finish
- High-luster Finish
- Convolute-constructed
- Large Area
- Large Area
- Deburring and Finishing
- Satin Finish
- Antique Finish
- Antique Finish

And in Column D I want something like this next to each item. Basically refining and regrouping into better categories now that I derived the important bits from the product descriptions.

- Portable
- Coating Removal (This should apply for coating removal and Removes Coatings)
- Coating Removal
- Coating Removal
- Smoothing, Deburring, and Finishing
- Coating Removal
- Coating Removal
- Convolute Wheel (This applies for Convolute Wheel and Convolute Constructed)
- Convolute Wheel
- Smoothing, Deburring, and Finishing
- Aesthetic Finish (This applies for Satin Finish, Antique Finish, and High luster finish)
- Aesthetic Finish
- Convolute Wheel
- For Large Areas
- For Large Areas
- Deburring and Finishing
- Aesthetic Finish
- Aesthetic Finish
- Aesthetic Finish

And for the question about the VLookup function. I have no idea what I'm doing.

I used this to get the keywords out of the descriptions, but I don't think I can use it for this because it needs the exact words and punctuation in order.
=LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH($A$2:$A$86,D2),$A$2:$A$86) Where D is the product description and A was where I listed the keywords to search for. I was also trying to alter this to regroup the keywords, but some I need to group are too dissimilar.

Comment: It's a little hard to picture what you are talking about. Can you share some examples of the data and formulas or expected output? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm thinking I could probably use CONCATENATE in some way, but it needs to return a new phrase instead of a string of the text involved. =CONCATENATE("Satin Finish", "High-Luster Finish", "Antique Finish") I guess I could temporarily sort the data so I can apply different functions where they're needed a little faster. Or maybe use this as a halfway step and apply it to all the data then recategorize based on the text strings? I feel like there's a better solution though.

Comment: Or maybe something like this?  =If(and(C2:C3273 = "Satin Finish"), "Aesthetic Finish", If(and(C2:C3273="High-luster Finish"), "Aesthetic Finish", If(and(C2:C3273="Antique Finish"), "Aesthetic Finish")))  This way seems overly cumbersome and time consuming though. And I probably don't have this correct, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a list of all the keywords with the new filters next to them. Searches for old keywords, then applies new filter next to it.
=LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH($E$2:$E$70,C2),$G$2:$G$70)